# Can I change a dll reference within a third-party dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

I've got two third-party dlls, which both are not strongly-named. I wanted to reference these dlls in `app.config` to be able to locate them once on the network and avoid copying multiple times for each application using them...As far as I understand, to reference them via `assemblyBinding` in `app.config` file they should be strongly-named:

```
<runtime>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="External"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="xxxx"/>
    <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="FILE://N://Lib/External.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
...
```

So I need to sign them. Thanks to [.NET-fu: Signing an Unsigned Assembly (Without Delay Signing)](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/) I managed to sign them with my `*.snk` file:

```
ildasm /all /out=Bar.il Bar.dll
ilasm /dll /key=Foo.snk Bar.il
```

Then I replaced references in my solution to the signed ones and set `CopyLocaly` to `false`. Afterwards I edited the `app.config` file with the new `publicKeyToken`.

However when running my application I still get `FileLoadException`, saying that loader cannot find one of these dlls with `publicKeyToken=null`.

So I decided that one these dlls references the other, and that reference definetely does not know anything about the signed version of the other dll.

Here comes the question: is there a way to change the reference inside the first dll to the signed version of the second one? Or my only options would be not to use `app.config` for these dlls and load them manually in code with, say, `Assembly.LoadFrom`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appeared to be quite easy in the end. In the `*.il` file of the dll containing a reference to the second dll I found the following entry by the name of the second dll:

```
.assembly extern /*23000002*/ SecondDllName
{
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}
```

and I changed it to

```
.assembly extern /*23000002*/ SecondDllName
{
  .publickeytoken = (xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx )  
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}
```

i.e. added the generated public key token.

Then I reassembled the dll with

```
ilasm /dll /key=Foo.snk Bar.il
```

And it worked.